# Xamarin forms WebView - loaded page does not fire drag drop events

Tags: android, events, xamarin.forms, webview

I have a WebView on a Xamarin forms page. I'm trying to respond to drag/drop events within the javascript on that page. Here is the static HTML of the page used in the example:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2 id='hello'>Hello</h2>
<button onclick='changeToRed()'>Press Me</button>
<p>Drag area</p>
    <div class='container' id='List'>
        <p class='draggable' draggable='true' ondragstart='changeToGreen()'>One</p>
        <p id='two' class='draggable' draggable='true'><button>Two</button></p>  
    </div>   
<script>
(function () {

  changeHeadingBg('yellow');
    
  function dragstart_handler(ev) {
    changeToGreen();
  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('two');
    element.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart_handler);
  });
})();

    function changeHeadingBg(color){
            document.getElementById('hello').style.background = color;
    }
    function changeToRed(){
        document.getElementById('hello').style.background = 'red';
    }
    function changeToGreen(){
        document.getElementById('hello').style.background = 'green';
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you save this as a static html page and open it in a browser both of the text elements respond to a dragstart event by changing the  elements background colour (you can reset it in between by clicking the button). If I load the same html into a webview and attempt to interact with it, the drag events do not fire. I've tried various ways of setting up the events, including the two approaches currently on the page, but these events never fire. Other events, such as the onclick handler for the button, seem to fire okay. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my page xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <WebView x:Name="webView" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000"  />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

and here is the code behind for it - apologies for the nasty way of embedding the HTML, but it seemed the easiest way to create a self contained example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Test {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();

            var html = new HtmlWebViewSource {
                Html = GetHtml()
            };
            webView.Source = html;
        }

        private string GetHtml() {
            return @"
<html>
<body>
<h2 id='hello'>Hello</h2>
<button onclick='changeToRed()'>Press Me</button>

    <div class='container' id='List'>
        <p class='draggable' draggable='true' ondragstart='changeToGreen()'>Zero</p>
        <p id='two' class='draggable' draggable='true'>One</p>  
    </div>   

<script>
(function () {

    changeHeadingBg('yellow');

      function dragstart_handler(ev) {
    changeToGreen();
  }

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const element = document.getElementById('two');
    element.addEventListener('dragstart', dragstart_handler);
  });

})();

    function changeHeadingBg(color){
            document.getElementById('hello').style.background = color;
    }
    function changeToRed(){
        document.getElementById('hello').style.background = 'red';
    }
    function changeToGreen(){
        document.getElementById('hello').style.background = 'green';
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
";
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Different from Windows/Linux, the drag and drop data on Android is not available
when the drag starts. It is only available when the drop is performed (finger
releases from touch screen).You could look at [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=584789).

Comment: Thanks Leo, at least that has saved me from throwing effort at it. In the meantime I've looked around a bit, and found that the "draggable" library works in the webview on android, so I'll probably proceed that way

Comment: If you solve it you could send it as an answer and it will help others.